# How to completely uninstall docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I followed the uninstall instructions here. Then I ran these commands:

sudo apt-get purge docker-engine
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge docker-engine
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo apt-get purge docker-engine
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge docker-engine
rm -rf /var/lib/docker

So after I did all this I ran this command to see if docker files are any where else:

sudo find / -name '*docker*'

Answer (score 16):

To completely uninstall Docker:

Step 1

> dpkg -l | grep -i docker

To identify what installed package you have:

Step 2

> sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce
> docker-ce-cli
>
> sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io
> docker-ce

The above commands will not remove images, containers, volumes, or user created configuration files on your host. If you wish to delete all images, containers, and volumes run the following commands:

> sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker

> sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker

> sudo groupdel docker

> sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock

You have removed Docker from the system completely.